# Aligning HTML headings with image using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS, and I'm experiencing a lot of difficulty with aligning things.

At the moment, I have `<h1>` and `<h2>` text and an image. I'd like the `<h2>` text to reside right beneath the `<h1>` text, and I'd like this `<h1>-<h2>` block to be positioned in the top-left corner of the screen. I'd like the image to be inline with the text, but centered in the middle of the screen. This is what I have so far:

```
.header img {
    width: 525px;
    height: 188px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative:
}

.header h1{
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    top: 35px;
    font-family: 'Tehuti';
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: .2em .5em;
    color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);

}
.header h2{
    font-family: 'Tehuti';
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: .2em .5em;
    color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
    background-color: rgba(37, 39, 37, 0.07);
    float: left;
}
```

I can't for the life of me get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far to receive better help.

Comment: Relavent HTML and CSS code please

Comment: There's the most recent code. I've gone through a bunch of different tries though.

Comment: The `<h1>` `<h2>` and `<img>` are all contained in the class="header" div.

Comment: Post your HTML as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an `absolute` positioned layout your could `absolute` position your `<img>` to the center of the screen with these styles:

```
.header img {
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78kx8weg/3/) for a demo ([fullscreen](https://jsfiddle.net/78kx8weg/3/embedded/result/))

Comment: It seems that with this solution, the image is centered when the browser is full screen but aligns to the right when the window is resized.

Comment: @Danny Sorry my CSS was incorrect. Please see if this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78kx8weg/3/) works for you. I will update the answer

Comment: The new code is still giving me the same effect. Thanks for giving me a start though. I think I need to play around with the transform attribute.

Answer (score 0):

*1*: `text-align` aligned the content inside the element so setting `text-align: center` to `.header img` will no center align the img.

*2*: the `h1` and `h2` has by default `display: block` so that is why it place one bellow the other, set `display: inline-block` or `inline` to placed next to each other.

Now you can `float: left` `h1` and `h2` set `text-align: center` to `div .header` but you will note that the img will not centered in the middle of the screen

So do this

```css
h1, h2{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Tehuti';
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: .2em .5em;

    color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
}

.header h2{
    background-color: rgba(37, 39, 37, 0.07);
}

.header{
    text-align: center;
}

.header img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.h-content{
    position: absolute; /*If you want it to be always on the top-left of the screen, even when scrolls set fixed*/
    left: 15px;
    top: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="h-content">
        <h1>I'm a h1</h1>
        <h2>I'm a h2</h2>
    </div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1" alt=""/>
</div>
```

I hope this help you